# Structuring a Silverlight Application without MVVM

Tags: silverlight, architecture, refactoring

I have inherited a Silverlight application (using wcf services) that doesn't have a lot of structure to it (a lot of code in the code behind, some utility classes, 3 separate pages).

I have about a day to clean it up a bit so I can't really restructure it to use a MVVM pattern... and to be honest I don't think I have enough experience with MVVM to even do that well to the entire application even if I had more time.

Given those constraints any advice on changes that could help?

thanks.

Comment: What do you expect from answer? We are not telepathists and can't help you exactly. Advice in general: move code-behind to a separated class and try to get rid of errors (replace calls to the names of elements with properties, and replace event handlers with commands).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late but hope this helps:

- Set all fields, properties, methods etc in corrosponding regions.
- Make sure every aspect has a "///summary" part explaining what it does.
- Make sure every field is declared the same way. (not the one starting with a "-" and the other with a "=" as example).
  As well as properties.

Try to avoid having double data etc